# Is User mode driver mandatory for WDDM 1.1 if test application use only WIN32 GDI calls?

Tags: windows, graphics, driver

I am a newbie in Windows driver development. I am trying to learn to write a very basic dummy display driver in WDDM 1.1 driver architecture.

My doubt is a very basic question: Is User mode driver mandatory for WDDM 1.1 architecture. I have seen an alternative path like: 
Application -> Win32GDI -> Win32K.sys -> Dxgkrnl.sys -> Display Miniport driver (kernel mode driver)

So can I make only the display miniport driver and install it; ignoring the user mode driver development and installation and make at least a very basic driver working? My test applications shall use ony WIN32 GDI APIs.

One more query. where can I get a very basic sample of WDDM 1.1 driver? I have seen tutorials/dummy examples in codeproject for XPDM driver; but not for WDDM drivers. Please help..

Thank you for your understanding and patience,

Regards,

Lullaby

Comment: Yes.  Kernel-mode display drivers were responsible for the vast majority of blue-screen crashes.  They still bomb, I can reliably trigger a crash by playing Azkend 2 on my machine for example, but don't take the OS down with them anymore.  Required for DirectX, I suppose your stipulation that you only want to support GDI would be a backdoor.  You must like pain, using a remote kernel debugger isn't a lot of fun.